# Not Showing Movie, Black Screen Appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

My movie player is playing but does not play any video. It plays only the sound.

My code is given below:

```
    self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:nil];

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame=CGRectMake(10, (self.view.frame.size.height-200-64)/2, 300, 200);

    [self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    [self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    self.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
     [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AttachmentUrl]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

    self.moviePlayer.fullscreen=YES;
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.moviePlayer play];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieloadStateHandler:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Please suggest me what I will need to do.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that it is better to use: `MPMoviePlayerViewController`

For example:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mvPlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                               initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AttachmentUrl]];
```